# If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error "If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import in". I saw other stack flow questions and  I know the error is coming from views.py but I cannot seem to figure out where the error is

[image: Folder structure]

views.py/myapp

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hey,Welcome</h1>')
```

urls.py/myapp

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

urlpattern = [
    path('',views.index, name='index')
]
```

urls.py/myproject

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('myapp.urls'))
]

Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 698, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 481, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 706, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'myapp.urls' from 'E:\\projects\\django\\myproject\\myapp\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: could you also add your full traceback error body?

Comment: `myapp/urls.py` says `urlpattern =` et.c instead of `urlpatterns = `. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please just change `urlpattern` to `urlpatterns` in `urls.py/myapp` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Please read [answer]. Questions that are a matter of a simple typo should be closed and not answered.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: You are using the `reverse()` call on a field of a Class-based View and you need to use [`reverse_lazy()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you saved me a lot of time !

Answer (score 1):

besides the answer changing this line help to disappear the error

in my app(sub app) ->urls.py

change below line

from . import views

with

from appname import views

Comment: This was it for me. I literally copy/pasted from the tutorial and it still broke. Whoever said that naming things and cache invalidation were the hardest things in computer science never had to deal with paths...